# Database deadlock when firing triggers

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading

I use threading and when I commit data I get trigger deadlock. How to prevent database deadlock? Trigger check if row exist and if exist then do rollback..

I read this but it is not helpful much:

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2006/deadlocks/

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/16/sql-server-fix-error-1205-transaction-process-id-was-deadlocked-on-resources-with-another-process-and-has-been-chosen-as-the-deadlock-victim-rerun-the-transaction/

How to avoid this error?

code:

```
advertismentsDao.Save(ad);
advertismentsDao.CommitChanges();
```

and commit fires this trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_ViolateAdvertisements] ON [dbo].[Advertisements]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED ins JOIN dbo.Advertisements ad
                   ON ISNULL(ins.Price, 0) = ISNULL(ad.Price, 0)
                   AND ISNULL(ins.HollidayDuration, 0) = ISNULL(ad.HollidayDuration, 0)
                   AND ISNULL(ins.Name, 0) = ISNULL(ad.Name, 0)
                   AND ISNULL(ins.Description, 0) = ISNULL(ad.Description, 0)
                   AND ISNULL(ins.Cities_idCities, 0) = ISNULL(ad.Cities_idCities, 0)
                   AND ISNULL(ins.Areas_idAreas, 0) = ISNULL(ad.Areas_idAreas, 0)
                   AND ISNULL(ins.Countries_idCountries, 0) = ISNULL(ad.Countries_idCountries, 0)
                   AND ins.Agencies_idAgencies = ad.Agencies_idAgencies
                   --AND ins.Url = ad.Url
                   HAVING COUNT(1) > 1)
   BEGIN
       RAISERROR ('Unique constraint violation in dbo.Advertisements', 16, 1)
       ROLLBACK TRAN;
   END
END
```

But I get error:

> Transaction (Process ID 78) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the
>   transaction.
>   StackTrace:
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, DbAsyncResult result)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
>   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd)
>   at NHibernate.Id.IdentityGenerator.InsertSelectDelegate.ExecuteAndExtract(IDbCommand
>   insert, ISessionImplementor session)
>   at NHibernate.Id.Insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.PerformInsert(SqlCommandInfo
>   insertSQL, ISessionImplementor session, IBinder binder)

Comment: any idea how to prevent dead lock?

Comment: There is a large amount of information already available about analyzing and preventing deadlocks, including in the SQL Server documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188246.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191242.aspx What exactly is your question? You only said that the information you found is not helpful, but you didn't explain why.

Comment: Why are you trying to enforce a unique constraint via a trigger rather than a unique constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a unique constraint instead.

example:

```
Alter Table Advertisements
ADD Constraint Advertisements_UQ1 Unique (
   Price,
   HollidayDestination,
   Name,
   Description,
   Cities_idCities,
   Areas_idAreas,
   Countries_idCountries,
   Agencies_idAgencies
)
```